# how to get teamviewer to use entire, portrait oriented 3160 x 2160 monitor for remote laptop that is 3160 x 2160 landscape?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm remoting to two different laptops, both Dell Windows 10 with 3140 x 2160.
My local monitors are both 3840 x 2160 physically oriented for portrait (tall, not wide).

Connecting to Teamviewer on one remote fills the entire monitor and looks as if remote laptop is actually set for 3840 x 2160 portrait.  It's perfect.

THE PROBLEM:
But, remoting to 2nd monitor shows the exact image for the laptop's physical, landscape screen, using only the middle 1/3 of the monitor.

How do I configure display settings of 2nd Teamviewer connection to use entire portrait monitor to show 2nd remote laptop (desktop, and task bar etc below)?